# Generating random titles and descriptions in Python

Tags: python

Are there any python libraries which can generate random titles and random descriptions.

Random title: A grammatically correct(but random) English sentence with less than 5 words.
Random description: A grammatically correct(but random) English sentence with less than 20 words.

I am testing a product which has title and description field. I want to create multiple objects with random title and random descriptions instead of "Title 1" "Description 1".

Comment: I don't need more spam mail.

Comment: If you just want filler text, it seems a bit unnecessary to me to have the "grammatically correct" constraint. Why not just lorem ipsum text?

Comment: Last resort - Create 2 big files with several titles in one & descriptions in other (gathered from random sources on the internet). Load the files & fetch `random` titles & descriptions.

Answer (score 5):

For a fairly simple solution, just find matches for a regex like `[A-Z][a-z'\-]+[, ]([a-zA-Z'\-]+[;,]? ){15,25}[a-zA-Z'\-]+[.?!]` (Match a capitalized word followed by 15-25 words (potentially with commas or semicolons following them) then followed by a final word and an ending punctuation mark) in some large block of text. To get shorter, title-like phrases, you could just match any sequence of about 5 words (probably without punctuation between them): 
`([a-zA-Z'\-]+ ){4,6}`

---

From [Generating pseudo random text with Markov chains using Python](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/06/generating-pseudo-random-text-with-markov-chains-u/):

You can use Markov chains to achieve this. To do that, you'll need to do the following steps (from the page I linked):

> 1. Have a text which will serve as the corpus from which we choose the
>      next transitions.
> 2. Start with two consecutive words from the text.
>      The last two words constitute the present state.
> 3. Generating next
>      word is the markov transition. To generate the next word, look in
>      the corpus, and find which words are present after the given two
>      words. Choose one of them randomly.
> 4. Repeat 2, until text of required
>      size is generated.

The code they supply to accomplish this:

```
import random

class Markov(object):

    def __init__(self, open_file):
        self.cache = {}
        self.open_file = open_file
        self.words = self.file_to_words()
        self.word_size = len(self.words)
        self.database()


    def file_to_words(self):
        self.open_file.seek(0)
        data = self.open_file.read()
        words = data.split()
        return words


    def triples(self):
        """ Generates triples from the given data string. So if our string were
                "What a lovely day", we'd generate (What, a, lovely) and then
                (a, lovely, day).
        """

        if len(self.words) < 3:
            return

        for i in range(len(self.words) - 2):
            yield (self.words[i], self.words[i+1], self.words[i+2])

    def database(self):
        for w1, w2, w3 in self.triples():
            key = (w1, w2)
            if key in self.cache:
                self.cache[key].append(w3)
            else:
                self.cache[key] = [w3]

    def generate_markov_text(self, size=25):
        seed = random.randint(0, self.word_size-3)
        seed_word, next_word = self.words[seed], self.words[seed+1]
        w1, w2 = seed_word, next_word
        gen_words = []
        for i in xrange(size):
            gen_words.append(w1)
            w1, w2 = w2, random.choice(self.cache[(w1, w2)])
        gen_words.append(w2)
        return ' '.join(gen_words)
```

With this code, you then do something like the following example, replacing their jeeves.txt with some seed text of your choice (longer is better).

```
In [1]: file_ = open('/home/shabda/jeeves.txt')

In [2]: import markovgen

In [3]: markov = markovgen.Markov(file_)

In [4]: markov.generate_markov_text()
Out[4]: 'Can you put a few years of your twin-brother Alfred,
who was apt to rally round a bit. I should strongly advocate
the blue with milk'
```

After In[1] through In[3], you'd just need to call `markov.generate_markov_text()` with the proper arguments to generate sequences of 5 and 20 words as you needed them.